# How to install python extension "ms-python.python" in local linux server to debug the scrip in VScode

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, python-extensions

I ssh the server in VS code and when I install python extension in the VScode, I got "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate". May I know how can I install python extension in the linux server manually? Because I want to debug the script in VScode and the issue is the python extension cannot install in that linux server.

Thank you.

Comment: are yyou behind a proxy? If so, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3492

Comment: I set proxy and also tried ```"http.proxyStrictSSL": true,``` and install, I got the same issue